# Problem connecting to PostgresSql from Docker container

Tags: networking, server, docker, nginx, postgresql

I have two `Ubuntu Servers 20.04` with an external IP of 185.253.74.227
The first server has a local IP 192.168.1.30 on which I have `nginx` running and I host my Docker containers on it.
The second server has a local IP of 192.168.1.118 on which I have `PostgreSQL v12`

I have created a database and successfully connected to it both locally and configured external access so that my colleague can connect to it via `pgAdmin4`

```
"ConnectionStrings": "Server=185.253.74.227;Port=5432;Database=forex_crm; ;User Id=ampiex;Password=my_password;Trust Server Certificate=true;"
```

The problem appears when I run Docker Container

```
sudo docker run -d --name crm_front --network ampitex_default -p 3002:3002 ac0f95b5c3e0
sudo docker run -d --name crm_api --network ampitex_default -p 8080:80 75d048cb9146
```

`crm_front` - this is the client side of my application
`crm_api` - asp.net core web api application that should connect to the database

After running the containers, I try to log in to my application's website and get a 500 Internal Server Error.

docker logs crm_api

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'forex_crm' on server ''.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'AmpitexCrm.Repositories.Contexts.CRMContext'.
      System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
       ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 185.253.74.227:5432
       ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMVGERBOVK44", Request id "0HMVGERBOVK44:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
       ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 185.253.74.227:5432
       ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
```

I tried connecting to the database from the first server

```
root@ampitex:~# psql -h 185.253.74.227 -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432

psql (12.16 (Ubuntu 12.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Then from the crm_api container

```
root@ampitex:~# docker exec -it crm_api bash
root@3088e6d8fa7c:/app# psql -h 185.253.74.227 -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "185.253.74.227" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Now I'll  provide the configuration files and the results of my actions**

```
root@ampitex:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
3002                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       172.23.0.4
443/tcp on br-3abfdd99a830 ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp on br-3abfdd99a830 ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp on br-3abfdd99a830 ALLOW       172.23.0.4
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       172.23.0.4
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
```

Here I show you which network the container is on
root@ampitex:~# docker inspect 3088e6d8fa7c

```
                "Gateway": "172.22.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.22.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
                "DriverOpts": null
```

**Now, what I have on the second server**

```
root@database:~# netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      384242/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      384242/postgres
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1425099  384242/postgres      /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
root@database:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:19:99:df:31:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.118/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::219:99ff:fedf:3151/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@database:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       172.23.0.4
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
192.168.1.118 5432/tcp     ALLOW       Anywhere
192.168.1.118 5432/udp     ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       172.22.0.3
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
root@database:~# nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
local   all             all                                     peer

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
hostssl all             all          0.0.0.0/0                  md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    all             all              ::/128                 md5

root@database:~# nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'                                     
port = 5432                             
max_connections = 1000                  
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
```

I also tried creating a docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  crm_api:
    image: ampitexcrmapi:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING: "Server=postgres;Port=5432;Ssl Mode=Require;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=my_password;Trust Server Certificate=true;"

  crm_front:
    image: crm_front:latest
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
```

However, this has not yielded any results. I have tried many tips in my search for information and because of this my server already looks contaminated, which makes it worse. So I need your help, Any information you lack to understand the situation I will send. I'll be glad for any recommendations

Comment: It looks like the machine hosting your docker container isn't letting the containers' internal IP addresses forward to elsewhere. Try to ping the database host from within the container, and use `tcpdump` on both the docker host and the database host to look at the icmp traffic, see what's coming in and going out.